# Could not get the position in this observable

Tags: android, position, rx-java, rx-android

I need to get the first position I've received to make a list and to call adapter from recyclerView. So I've decided to implement an Observable and I do this:

```
    private void getLocation() {
    Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Location>()
    {
        LocationManager mLocationManager;
        public void call(final Subscriber<? super Location> subscriber)
        {
            final LocationListener listener = new LocationListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
                {
                    if (location != null)
                    {
                        Log.v("Location Changed", location.getLatitude() + " and " + location.getLongitude());
                        subscriber.onNext(location);

                      try
                      {
                          mLocationManager.removeUpdates(this);
                      }
                      catch (SecurityException e)
                      {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                      }

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

                }
            };
            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

         try
         {
            Location location = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

           if(location != null && location.getTime() > Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - 2 * 60 * 1000)
          {
             subscriber.onNext(location);
          }
          else
          {
              Looper.prepare();
              mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);
              mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);
          }
      }
      catch (SecurityException e)
      {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }




      }
  }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .subscribe(new Subscriber<Location>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted()
        {
            adapter = new AirportAdapter(getActivity(), airps,nearby);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Location location)
        {
         Log.d("lat",String.valueOf(location));
            getNearbyAirports(location);
        }
    });

}
private void getNearbyAirports(Location location)
{
  nearby = new RealmList<>();
  double currLatitude = location.getLatitude();
  double currLongitude = location.getLongitude();

  for(Airport aobj : airps)
  {
      if((aobj.getLatitudeDeg() >= (currLatitude - 0.5 ))&&
        (aobj.getLatitudeDeg() <= (currLatitude + 0.5 ))&&
        (aobj.getLongitudeDeg() >= (currLongitude - 0.5 ))&&
        (aobj.getLongitudeDeg() <= (currLatitude + 0.5 )))
        {
         nearby.add(aobj);
        }
  }

    Log.d("nearby",String.valueOf(nearby.size()));

}
```

the problem is that I don't receive error, it only implements recyclerView with empty items.

It's possible that it's a problem of Observable? or a Looper?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You didn't call Subscriber.onError(Throwable e), the created observable simpy don't notify about errors (altough you might catch them in the try block).
 When creating observable, you must call Subscriber.onError(Throwable e) method in order to notify the subscriber about error events